# Searching symbols, non-letter characters in Google

Tags: google-search, special-characters

I'd like to search the internet for a string containing a few symbols, namely dashes, pipes and angle brackets.

I tried searching for them by typing them into Google but it seems to ignore the symbols.

Any advice?